# Unable to get T3i to shoot video in manual mode

Tags: video, canon, shooting

I am sure I am missing something here. I have a host of cameras but bought a T3i recently. I am trying to get it to shoot video in Manual mode but as soon as I click the "Live View" button to start recording, it turns off live view and I get a blank, black screen.

Here is what I do from start to finish. Please tell me what I am missing:

1. I switch on my T3i by sliding the On/Off slider to the On position on the top of the camera.
2. I turn the dial on the top to **M** to go into manual mode.
3. I click the **Live View** button that's next to the LCD panel. It starts to show me whatever is in the front of the camera on the LCD screen.
4. Next, I want to start recording, so I hit the "Live View" button again, assuming that is how it will start recording. But at this point, the LCD screen shuts itself off.

If in step 4, instead of pressing the **Live View** button, I hold down the shutter, it clicks a picture instead of shooting video.

I'd just like to shoot video on this camera in Manual mode. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. It's a bit quirky little trick.

You do not turn the dial to **M** but turn it to the little picture that shows the video camera.

Now, though you'll be able to set the shutter speed and aperture, you won't be able to change the ISO.

To be able to change the ISO, click the **Menu** button to the top-left of the LCD screen, then from the menu, select **Manual** as the value for the **Movie Exposure** setting.

Now, you can change the ISO as well.

I figured it out by looking [here](http://photography.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-shoot-video-on-your-canon-rebel--photo-12747) and [here](http://www.dvxuser.com/V6/showthread.php?248318-How-do-you-film-with-the-T3i-in-quot-manual-quot-mode&s=bd38a6e9321cdd451f015f30b6126483&p=2331102&viewfull=1#post2331102).